# Sequences and reflexivity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Assume X to be a real reflexive Banach space. Why are sequential topological notions topological notions ? (relatively to the weak topology on X and the weak star topology on X*) For ex : sequentially closed set is closed,
sequentially compact set is compact, and so on.

For compact set : by using the Eberlein-Šmulian Theorem, we get the result.

Question : How can we proceed for closed sets and continuous mappings ?.

Thanks.